# What would keep iPad from showing in lsusb?

Tags: 14.04, usb

What would keep iPad from showing in lsusb? The cable was working earlier (I use libimobiledevice 1.2), and is not a charge-only cable. The USB port works because I plug in an Android to it and it shows it immediately.

I restarted the iPad considering it might be a problem on its side. It still does not show, and shows the same number of lines in `lsusb` with or without it plugged in.

Comment: Am I right in thinking, you just want to mount the Ipad as a folder?

Comment: Could be a problem with the iPad - do you have a Windows computer to try with ?

Comment: This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the cable that comes with these devices is a bit flimsy. Another usb cable worked.